# wsp deployment issue

Tags: solution-package

We did wsp deployment in our farm (we have 5 WFE and 2 CA).

The wsp was deployed successfully. But it is not effected. When we are looking in the system still it is showing previous deployment. that package contains event receiver and application pages.

Event receiver working fine but application pages are not working fine.

We did trouble shoot steps as below:

1. After Retracted & removed  WSP -->

we verified GAC_MSIL is removed solution folder and dll or not... it is removed.

We verified _layout folder is all application pages are removed or not... it is removed

2. After deployed -->

we verified GAC_MSIL is updated dll is there or not.... it is there with updated (versions both file version and product version)-- it is updated

We verified is all application pages are updated one or not under _layout folder... it is updated

we restarted the timerjobs and iis.-- but no use.

we try with host entry by ip by ip... but no use.

but the same package working perfectly in dev server.

Please give me your suggestion.

Comment: Did you made IIS reset after both "Retract & remove" and after "Deploy" operations?